# Testing a method accepting a delegate with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, delegates, moq

my code is using a component implementing an interface like this

```
public interface IFoo 
{ 
    void DoSomething(string p1);

    void DoSomething(string p1, Action<string> p2);
}
```

As of this moment, I'm using the first method, but I plan to move to the second one and I want to keep my coverage as high as possible.

Just that I really don't know how to inspect the delegate or even just setup Moq to mock the interface.

I tried with

```
mock.Setup(p => p.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Delegate>()));
mock.Setup(p => p.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Action<string>>()));
```

but neither will let me build. Any suggestion?

Comment: I didn't want to bloat the post with obvious code =)

Comment: well don't bloat but some details on what does not work (is there a compile error? if so can you post it?) would be helpful

Comment: Your `mock.Setup(...` lines are unbalanced (they're missing close-parens for the Setup().  Is that just a copy-paste error?  When I fix that, your second line (It.IsAny<Action<string>>()) works fine for me.

Comment: It is a copy-paste error. And, indeed, now it builds. Still, it would be interesting to be able to do some kind of assert on the content of the Action.

Comment: But what would that give you?  You'll be mocking the IFoo when you have some other method Bar under test, and you know that Bar will call `This.myFoo.DoSomething("bar", myAction);`  For a test on Bar, it doesn't matter what the Foo object does with the action passed to it; IFoo doesn't return any data.  Are you relying on side effects of the Action p2 in your code that calls `DoSomething`?

Comment: Exactly as you said. I'm relying on side effects of p2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line:

```
mock.Setup(p => p.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Delegate>()));
```

must **not** compile becaue `DoSomething` requires an `Action<string>`, and `Delegate` is not *implicitly* convertible to `Action<string>`. Your other line:

```
mock.Setup(p => p.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Action<string>>()));
```

works and is correct!

You can setup only when `p2` satisfies some criterion, for example:

```
mock.Setup(p => p.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(),
    It.Is((Action<string> p2) => p2 != null && p2.Target is SomeClass)
    ));
```

Or you can use `CallBack` to check things:

```
mock.Setup(p => p.DoSomething(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Action<string>>()))
    .CallBack((string p1, Action<string> p2) =>
    {
        // your code (for example Asserts) here,
        // use p2
    });
```

Of course, **there is a limit to how much you can inspect an `Action<string>`**, but you can see if it is non-null, see if its `p2.Target` is non-null or has a specific type or equals a given instance, you can see if `p2.Method` is a known (named) method, or you could use `p2.GetInvocationList()` if you expect a so-called multicast delegate.

Comment: Thank you! your answer gave me an idea that helped me solve the issue. What I did was simply extracting a service that would take care of handling the logic of the Action. In the tests, I simply verified that the second service was correctly invoked.