# How to mock and expect a method with Action delegate as one of the parameter with Moq

Tags: asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I am using Automapper in my .net core application to map. I have a method like below

```
public MyEntity TransformtoToEntity(MyDTO dto)
        {
            var entity = _mapper.Map<MyEntity, MyDTO>(dto, opts => opts.Items["isUpdate"] = "N");

            return entity;
        }
```

My test method looks like

```
    [Fact]
            public void Returns_Data_After_Mapping()
            {
                // Arrange
                var mockEntityData = new MyEntity
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "John"

                };
var mockDto = new MyDTO
            {
                Id = 1,
Name = "John"
            };
                var mappingOperationMock = new Mock<IMappingOperationOptions<MyDTO, MyEntity>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
                mappingOperationMock.Setup(x => x.Items).Returns(new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "isUpdate", "N" }});

                _mapper.Setup(x => x.Map(It.IsAny<MyDTO>(), 
                    It.IsAny<Action<IMappingOperationOptions<MyDTO, MyEntity>>>()))
                   .Returns(mockEntityData);

                // Act
                var result = _myMapper.TransformDtoToEntity(mockDto);

                // Assert
                Assert.NotNull(result);

                _mapper.VerifyAll();
                mappingOperationMock.VerifyAll();
            }
```

Here how can I verify that IMappingOperationOptions parameters are correctly passed. Or is there any better way to do a unit test here. Basically I am stuck with how to effectively unit test methods who are having Action delegate parameters. I referred the thread [Testing a method accepting a delegate with Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594860/testing-a-method-accepting-a-delegate-with-moq), but could not find anything I can assert or verify inside the callback.

Comment: There is no need to mock AM, you can simply include AM in the tests.

Comment: For everyone who didn't realized it that for: AutoMapper **was NOT MEANT to transform data back to entities or domain models**, just **don't do it... NEVER**. Domain -> ViewModel, Domain -> DTO, Entity -> ViewModel, Entity -> DTO. See Jimmy Bogard's (AutoMapper Author) [blog post on two-way-mapping](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/), especially _I think using AutoMapper because you don’t want to use the “=” operator is a bit lazy_.

Comment: Also what is it exactly that you want to test? when you mock AutoMapper, and thats the only thing your method does, what are you testing then? Testing AutoMapper itself isnt your task, thats what the Library author does (or should do). The test just makes no sense. Also what is `_mockDto`, its never declared int he code, neither is `_mapper`. you are setting up `mappingOperationMock`, but never use it, you never call it's `mappingOperationMock.Object`. Its really not clear what you try to achieve.

Comment: o you want to **integration** test your mapping? Setup AutoMapper same way as you do it in your application, and pass a model to it and check the result. No Mocking involved. You use Mocking when you what to change a desired result from a method or property, so you can test a specific case (which is otherwise hard to set  up)

Comment: @Tseng. I have gone through the blog. In the comments sections, people have different opinion as well. Could you please elaborate why two way mappings are bad. Sorry I could not get the point

Comment: @Sajan: Jimmy Bogard, the author of the blog post is the one who did create AutoMapper. He'll should know above **ANYONE ELSE** for which use cases AutoMapper was created for and for which **it wasn't**. The people in the comments, don't understand the issues (imho bad software developers). Jimmy summarized it in a  single sentance quoted above: _I think using AutoMapper because you don’t want to use the “=” operator is a bit lazy._ That's not what automapper was made for to "replace" the "=" operator.

Comment: You nee the right tool for the right problem, and AutoMapper is the **WRONG** tool for mapping Dtos back to Entity or Domain models. This will cause all kind of issues with ORM Frameworks, especially Entity Framework. It will not work in general. It may work in a limited case, but once it gets more complex you may bite your teeth off. Search for [dont use Automapper for ORM](www.google.com/search?q=don't+use+Automapper+for+ORM&oq=don't+use+Automapper+for+ORM) on google to find out why its a horrible idea

Comment: @Tseng Sometimes people change their minds...  :) that blog post is from 2019.
I would say that the quote "I think using AutoMapper because you don’t want to use the “=” operator is a bit lazy. " can still stand but the two way mapping is there and used. that doesn't mean that people are bad software developers :)

Comment: @FernandoMoreira: People don't do two-way mappings for a good reason. There are a couple of blog posts about it. Essentially it sums up that if you do two-way bindings, it mess up pretty bad with your ORM, especially if its tracking changes (such as Entity Framework) and you need to do all kind of stunts, producing hard to read and maintainable code. In simple demo-like tutorials you wont notice that but in real world apps it hurts big. For Domain Aggregate same applies. For two-way binding, you need mutable properties, which effectively defeats the purpose of an encapsulated domain

Comment: @FernandoMoreira: Have a read on [WHY MAPPING DTOS TO ENTITIES USING AUTOMAPPER AND ENTITYFRAMEWORK IS HORRIBLE](https://rogerjohansson.blog/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/) why its horribly bad idea. AutoMapper -> Entity may work in very simple cases (CRUD w/o any navigation properties), but in a real world application you just get yourself deeper into spaghetti code if you use it

Comment: And since we are at it, some comments form the author himself: https://twitter.com/jbogard/status/681514006620827648 : _Q: "How do I mock out AutoMapper for a unit test" A: don't._

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to test what is happening in your action delegate you can use the callback from moq.

Something like

```
Action<IMappingOperationOptions<MyEntity, MyDto>> mappingOperationAction = default;

_mapper.setup(x.Map(myDto, It.IsAny<Action<IMappingOperationOptions<MyEntity,MyDto>>>())
       .callBack<MyDto, Action<IMappingOperationOptions<MyEntity,MyDto>>>( (callbackMyDto, callbackMappingOperationAction) => mappingOperationAction = callbackMappingOperationAction);

var mappingOperation = new MappingOperationOptions<MyEntity, MyDto>(_ => default);

mappingOperationAction.Invoke(mappingOperation);

Assert.AreEqual("N", mappingOperation.Items["isUpdate"])
```